# Need to add toggle effect to this: jQuery("ul.tabs-nav").tabs("> .pane");

Tags: jquery

Good day, I'm new to Javascript and I'm editing a Wordpress website, I need to add the toggle effect to this line:

jQuery`("ul.tabs-nav").tabs("> .pane");`

I researched something and found this:

`$("#tabs").tabs( { fx: { height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' } } );`

But I don't have any idea on how to add it without removing the "> .pane"

The code is from a Wordpress Theme I have (PHP):

```
    $out ='
    <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function($){ jQuery("ul.tabs-nav").tabs("> .pane"); }); </script>

        <div class="post-tabs'.$type.'">
        '.do_shortcode($content).'
        </div>
    ';
   return $out;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post HTML as well ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit of a beginner too, but I recently found how to do this.

Add {show: { effect: "blind", duration: 1000 },
    hide: { effect: "blind", duration: 1000 }} in your tabs() like so:

```
     $out ='
    <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(document).ready(function($){ jQuery("ul.tabs-nav").tabs({show: { effect: "blind", duration: 1000 },
hide: { effect: "blind", duration: 1000 }) }); </script>

        <div class="post-tabs'.$type.'">
        '.do_shortcode($content).'
        </div>
    ';
   return $out;
```

I've excluded the "> .pane" because I don't know how to include it with proper syntax.